# PHP recursively get parent key

Tags: php

For all the non numeric keys in the following array of objects, I'm trying to get the immediate parent key. If the immediate parent key is the first level index then I just get null. This will run on big batches of data so performance is somewhat important. $values can have many Objects and not just one as in this example.

EDIT here's some json, slightly different data / structure but same rules apply https://pastebin.com/raw/1ZyGZPCr

```
$values = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7320340
            [name] => 1373377
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file1.jpg
                    [1] => file2.jpg
                )
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 1
                    [width] => 3
                )
            [info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 123
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [postal] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [country] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => Australia
                                [code] => AUS
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )                    

        )

)
```

Desired output would be

```
id:null
name:null
images:null
attributes:null
height:attributes
width:attributes
info:null
value:info
location:info
postal:location
country:postal
name:country
code:country
```

Note that for objects with numeric keys (ex: images) I don't need the parent keys. My code so far

```
$array_iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator( $values );
$iterator_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $array_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY );
foreach ( $iterator_iterator as $key => $value ) {
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $iterator_iterator->getDepth()+1; $i++ ) {    
        $k = $iterator_iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
        if(!is_int($k)) {
            // if current element is array, then get key of object one level up ... ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `var_export` will work.

Comment: Sure give me a min

Comment: Here you go https://pastebin.com/raw/1ZyGZPCr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just a standard recursive function will suffice? I am going off your json string you posted:

```
function recParent($arr,&$new,$parent=false)
{
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key))
                $new[]  =   (!is_numeric($parent) && !empty($parent))? $key.':'.$parent : $key.':null';
            recParent($value,$new,$key);
        }
        else {
            if(!is_numeric($key))
                $new[]  =   (!is_numeric($parent) && !empty($parent))? $key.':'.$parent : $key.':null';
        }
    }
}
# Final array store (saves the rows)
$store  =   [];
# Loop rows
foreach($arr as $key => $row) {
    # Reset the $new array on every iteration so you don't just
    # overwrite the same array
    $new    =   [];
    # Recurse
    recParent($row,$new);
    # Store the current row and implode the key/values
    $store[$key]    =   implode(PHP_EOL,$new);
}

print_r($store);
```

Should give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id:null
publisherId:null
photos:null
attributes:null
width:attributes
height:attributes
info:null
val1:info
val2:info
location:info
address:location
country:address
destination:location
country:destination
online:null
    [1] => id:null
publisherId:null
photos:null
attributes:null
width:attributes
height:attributes
info:null
val1:info
val2:info
location:info
address:location
country:address
destination:location
country:destination
online:null
)
```

On the presumption that all the arrays are the same structure, just use the first array:

```
$new    =   [];
# Recurse once
recParent($arr[0],$new);
# Implode that one array
$final = implode(PHP_EOL,$new);
print_r($final);
```

That will only give you:

```
id:null
publisherId:null
photos:null
attributes:null
width:attributes
height:attributes
info:null
val1:info
val2:info
location:info
address:location
country:address
destination:location
country:destination
online:null
```

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so late - just wanted to say it seems to work perfectly. Thanks!